# Change Java Runtime Version in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, heroku, intellij-idea

I am deploying a server built with **ktor** to **Heroku**, but when I run command
`heroku open` I receive Application error

Following is shown in the logs

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`

When I run `heroku run java -version`
I receive this

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312-heroku"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-heroku-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b05, mixed mode)
```

How can I change the Java Runtime version in **Intellij idea**

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the Java version on Heroku where you deploy the application (by default Heroku provides Java 8, as you correctly verified).

In the project root place a file `system.properties` which contains:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change not the java Runtime version of IDEA, but the [JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#change-module-sdk) you use to [build](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#compile_module) the project to a lower version. See [Project SDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-settings-and-structure.html#project-sdk).